# How to save a list of pytorch models

Tags: python, pytorch

This is a newbie question. I have trained 8 pytorch convolutional models and put them in a list called models. I can use them for prediction so they are working. I would like to save them. I can't even work out how to save one however. I tried:

> `torch.save(models[0].save_dict(), "test.pth"`)

but this gives me:

> ModuleAttributeError: 'Net' object has no attribute 'save_dict'

`type(models[0])` gives me `__main__.Net`

How can I save this list of models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save model weights for one model (example the 1st) you should do

```py
torch.save(models[0].state_dict(), "test0.pth")
```

And to load it back you should instantiate a new object and load weights

```py
model0 = Net() # or however you instantiate the model in the first place 

model0.load_state_dict(torch.load("test0.pth"))
```

You can save your other models this way.

And don't forget to call model.eval() if you are using it for inference

If you want to save all models weights using a for loop

```py
for i, m in enumerate(models):
    torch.save(m.state_dict(), f"test{i}.pth")
```

And to load them all, supposing your model instantiation is something like follow :

```py
models = [Net() for i in range(8)]  # Note that you should adapt this to whatever method you use to create your models in the first place

for i, m in enumerate(models):
    m.load_state_dict(torch.load(f"test{i}.pth"))
    # if you are using it for inference uncomment the line below
    # m.eval()
```

and that's it your variable `models` is ready for use

Last but not least you can save the whole at once (but discouraged approach)

```py
torch.save(models, "all_models.pth")

# to load back
models = torch.load("all_models.pth")
```

However, This will cause error if you try to load models for example from another python script where the definition of your class `Net` is not available

Comment: Don't you always need the class Net() to be available to load the models? The line `models = [Net() for i in range(8)]` also needs Net().

Comment: Yeah you're right. However according to pytorch doc the first method is preferred as the second one can cause errors when your directory stucture changes (see https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-entire-model). Another advantage of the first approach is that you can redefine change your `Net` class definition and still be able to use your weights as long as your new class, say `Net2` has the same weights structure as `Net`